# Фильтрация выгрузки из Битрикс24 через REST API в гугл таблицу

Tags: битрикс

Пытаюсь выгрузить данные по задачам из Битрикс24 через Rest API в гугл таблицу, использую для этого метод tasks.task.list. В документации указанно что фильтрацию для TITLE можно производить по шаблону, задаю шаблон но фильтрация не происходит, при том что другие заданные параметры работают. Искомое значение всегда находится в начале TITLE

````
    'filter':{'<=CLOSED_DATE':'2023-11-31','GROUP_ID':544,'TITLE':'Брак%'},
    'select':['ID','TITLE','DESCRIPTION','CREATED_DATE','CLOSED_DATE','CLOSED_BY','CREATED_BY','END_DATE_PLAN']```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

разобрался самостоятельно. Символ % нужно было добавлять к самому значению фильтруемого поля
`'%TITLE':'Брак'`

Comment: Отметьте свой ответ как решение